can i replace onerror attribute in img tag with jquery
Up to now i used the onerror attribute method as fallback for images. onerror is problematic for csp. Is it valid to catch the error with jquery like so?
$(".element").on('error',function(){
  $(this).attr('src','old.png');
});

Thanks for any hint.

The question is unclear. please add more details

I think the question is clear, but my hint would be to try it. You've got the code, all you need is to use it. Then you know.

The simple answer is "yes". You can use .on() for any event, there's nothing special about onerror that would make it different.

thanks a lot for the positive feedback.
